# Change color of Input field depending on if there is a match

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying something pretty simple i guess, but i cant seem to get it work properly.
So i am using an input field to filter out an array of objects, which works medium good at the moment – (that means i am not sure if the condition is set up properly – sometimes it shows the right results, sometimes it doesnt.)

anyway i would like to change the background color depending on if there are objects matching the input or not.

Please can somebody help me fix this?
This is my code:

```
const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(true)
  const style = (isValid ? 'searched' : '');


  const searchItems = (searchValue) => {
    setSearchInput(searchValue)
    if (searchInput !== '') {

        const filteredData = allData.filter((project) => {
            return Object.values(project).join('').toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())
            
        })
        setFilteredResults(filteredData)
        setIsValid(true)
    }
    else{
        setFilteredResults(allData)
        setIsValid(false)

    }
}
```

and the input:

```
<label className="searchbar">
  <input  
    className={style}
    placeholder="A Visual Practice"
    onFocus={(e) => e.target.placeholder = "Search for?"} 
    onBlur={(e) => e.target.placeholder = "A Visual Practice"}
    onChange={(e) => searchItems(e.target.value)}
  />
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

After setting the searchInput State, the component will be re-rendered. So what I would is the following:

- Use the style state for checking if the input is valid or not and instead of storing a string, store a boolean (true for a valid input). I would call this state isValid and setIsValid.
- Before the return of the component, create a constant for your styling

  const style = `${isValid ? 'searched' : ''}`;

Because the component will be re-rendered every time you change a state, the style constant will be changed based on the isValid state. This constant can then be used as a class for your component.

Comment: Thank you for helping, but i am quite new to javascript, i ve tried to implement your would-dos but i cant get it to work, i've edited the code above – can you take a look at this and tell me what i am doing wrong please?